# Electron Link to web page

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I've had some software created in Electron and I have a menu on my first page.

The code for the page is at the bottom of this post. I'd like the first item "Resources For Teachers" to be a web link. I'm not a programmer so I will need help with this please. If it could open internally that would be even better.

This is the link it will be opening:

https://rhythmstix.co.uk/getting-started-your-bandlab-classroom

This is how it appears:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcmCi.jpg)

Here's the github link:

https://github.com/mbash12/reverse

This is a link to my software :

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/c0rrkp46u4xgr9x/AACiP0jE3dHK9br2OlWr_r3ia?dl=0

```
[
    {
        "name":"<u>Resources For Teachers</u></b>",
        "url":"guide",
        "type":"slides"
    },
    {
        "name":"Lesson 1 - Drumatic!",
        "url":"1.drumatic",
        "type":"slides"
    },
    {
        "name":"Lesson 2 - Looptastic",
        "url":"2.looptastic",
        "type":"slides"
    },
    {
        "name":"Lesson 3 - It's as easy as ABC",
        "url":"3.abc",
        "type":"slides"
    },
    {
        "name":"Lesson 4 - Using a stimulus preparation",
        "url":"4.stimulus",
        "type":"slides"
    },
    {
        "name":"Lesson 5 - Using a stimulus development",
        "url":"4.stimulus",
        "type":"slides"
    },
    {
        "name":"Lesson 6 - WALL-E - Day at work preparation",
        "url":"6.wall-e",
        "type":"slides"
    },
    {
        "name":"Lesson 6 - WALL-E - Day at work development",
        "url":"6.wall-e",
        "type":"slides"
    },
    {
        "name":"Lesson 7 - Quiz time",
        "url":"7.quiz",
        "type":"slides"
    }
]
```

Comment: From the [`java` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info): "*Java (**not to be confused with JavaScript or JScript or JS**) ...*". From the [`javascript` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*JavaScript (**not to be confused with Java**) ...*". Changing tag `java` to `javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

I never used Electron but maybe change it to

```
{
   "name":"<a href='https://rhythmstix.co.uk/getting-started-your-bandlab- 
           classroom'>Resources For Teachers</a></b>",
   "url":"guide",
   "type":"slides"
},
```

Comment: Thanks for trying - json doesn't like this, unfortunately. This element you've altered  is literally the name that appears - not the link..

Comment: I was already afraid that it wouldn't work. I don't have enough information to help you. I am sorry.